# How to display RadDataForm Valueproviders with key value pair

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I resolve most of my problem only few left out of which this one is preventing me to submit the form. I am using Nativescript + vue and without Typescript. how to display the Valueproviders with array list? Here is the code

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=2oWObE

Comment: When asking questions, code etc. needs to be here. Otherwise there's a risk that in the future the question is useless if link doesn't work.

Comment: Refer the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/DataForm/Editors/dataform-editors-overview#converters), you may use Converters.

Comment: Hi Manoj Its in Typescript I don't know typescript. After a struggling this I am posting.  I thought Playground is the best place to view the code James.  Its Just a click away still not happy will post it.

Answer (score 0):

There was the problem with your data type. As per the documentation Array should have `key` and `label` properties. But still if you want id and name then you should try like below.

```
'valuesProvider': {
    key: 'id',
    label: 'name',
    items: [
      { id: 1121, name: 'Shanghai' },
      { id: 3651, name: 'Lagos' },
      { id: 5213, name: 'Moscow' },
      { id: 6214, name: 'São Paulo' },
      { id: 6985, name: 'Sydney' }
    ]
  };
```

https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/DataForm/dataform-editors-providers

Anyway, I tried that and that was not working for me either then searched for it and relaised that there is an open feature request to support the valuesProvider for picker from JSON metadata. You can vote to support the same feature.

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/369

Comment: So Json Array is not possible then I try out hardcoding that was still not working check the same example. And what If I am fetching for http request How do I add it to valueprovider. I updated the code with your data still something is broken

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=rqK7wO&v=3

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Just get you cityList out of vue data and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) your data

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=2oWObE&v=6

more detailed version with groups

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=rqK7wO&v=3